# Why the progressBar show the progress from the end to the start counting backward?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int countUploadMsg = 0;

private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    allLoadedMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>();
    OpenPop.Mime.Message loadedMessage = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\test\");
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        loadedMessage = OpenPop.Mime.Message.Load(file);
        allLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
        int nProgress = (files.Length - counter + 1) * 100 / files.Length;
        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
        counter += 1;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbt1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    pbt1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    pbt1.Invalidate();
    lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
      allLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Headers.From.ToString(),         //From Column
      allLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Headers.Subject,                 //Subject Column
      allLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Headers.DateSent.ToString()      //Date Column
    }));

    countUploadMsg += 1;
}
```

The variable `pbt1` is the `ProgressBar`.

What I see is the `ProgressBar` green color at 100% also the text is 100% and then it start moving backward both the green color and the text 100% 99% 98%....

Maybe something with the calculation I'm doing:

```
int nProgress = (files.Length - counter + 1) * 100 / files.Length;
```

And the `files.Length` also should be `files.Length-1`?

Comment: Yes, it is your calculation. Your `counter` is increasing, while your `files.Length` is constant. The `nProgress` will be less and less. Thus you get 100% down to 0%.

Comment: You're right about the calculation - if you start with subtracting the counter from files length you obviously will start at 100%. You have to go with something like `int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.length` and increment the counter before reporting so you don't need the +1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you get it right. It is your calculation.

```
int nProgress = (files.Length - counter + 1) * 100 / files.Length;
```

Your `counter` is increasing because of `counter += 1;`, while your `files.Length` is constant. Then the `nProgress` will certainly become less and less due to the above calculation. Therefore, you get 100% down to 0%.

Should you not do it the other way round, that is: to use counter as progressive indicator?

```
int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length; //use counter here...
```

Also, you may want to increase the counter before calling the background worker progress:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    loadedMessage = OpenPop.Mime.Message.Load(file);
    allLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
    counter += 1; //put before the progress;
    int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
}
```